# How to cancel same requests in Vue js?

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm using axios <0.22 version so I can use cancelToken but I dont understand how I can use it
I tried but it doesnt work. Help me please. How cancel requests if they are calling same endpoint?

```js
let req = {}
const authInterceptors = (cfg) => {
  const config = cfg;
  req = cfg;
  config.headers.common['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = antiForgeryToken;
  if (req[config.url]) {
    req[config.url].cancel('Automatic cancellation')
  }

  const axiosSource = axios.CancelToken.source()
  req[config.url] = { cancel: axiosSource.cancel }
  config.cancelToken = axiosSource.token
  return config;
};
const errorInterceptors = (error) => {
  return Promise.reject(error);
};
const httpClient = axios.create({
  headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' },
  adapter: throttleAdapterEnhancer(<AxiosAdapter>axios.defaults.adapter, { threshold: 3 * 1000 }),
});

httpClient.interceptors.request.use(authInterceptors, errorInterceptors);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, just know `CancelToken` according to docs:

> is deprecated since v0.22.0 and shouldn't be used in new projects

To use `CancelToken`, there's just 3 steps:

1. create a `CancelToken`
2. assign that token to a request
3. invoke the method on `CancelToken`

```js
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
const source = CancelToken.source();

axios.post('/user/12345', {
  name: 'new name'
}, {
  cancelToken: source.token
})

// cancel the request (the message parameter is optional)
source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');
```

or

```js
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let cancel;

axios.get('/user/12345', {
  cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
    // An executor function receives a cancel function as a parameter
    cancel = c;
  })
});

// cancel the request
cancel();
```

Docs: https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation

Comment: I read this but I dont understand how to use it in my project. How to compare two requests and if they are same  cancel first of them @captainskippah